# Algorithm for detecting Voltage levels in a voltage vs time data/waveform

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing, simulation, waveform, quantization

I am analyzing a voltage output that I get from spice simulator and I want to quantize the time sampled voltage data so that I can convert the given (trapezoidal wave) to a square wave.[image]

I have tried differentiation as a method to understand when the data is at flat level(one of the voltage levels) or when it is in transition, but since there are inherent glitches in the voltage vs time data I am not able to get the exact levels that I want. The waveform extracted is from simulator and I am doing all the analysis in "C" language.

[Voltage waveform with a glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRtkN.png)

Comment: It's easy with the ideal input that you've shown. So you need to show what the real-world input looks like. In general, you'll want to run the input through a low-pass filter to remove some of the noise, and then hope that the signal-to-noise ratio is high enough that you can reliably identify the signal levels that you're looking for.

Comment: "inherent glitches in the voltage": please show us.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have added an example of voltage wavform with glitch in the above description. Could you please look into it and share your opinion?

Comment: It is a pity that you left all those squares. Find sections where the first derivative is small and use them to delimit the plateaus. [I was quite right to ask a picture, your diagrams are misleading.]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods to deal with this kind of a problem, but a nice solution to this will be the following:

1. Convolve the signal with a gaussian kernel, thus canceling out the noise at the cost of making the transitions between the levels slower
2. Due to the convolution, the transition will not be linear but there will be a place in the transition where the curvature changes sign, which is the location of the original edge. To find these locations, compute the Laplacian, which is simply the second derivative in 1D and look for places the Laplacian crosses 0.
3. To avoid the undershoot and overshoot, take a buffer of a few samples from the found edges and compute the mean, thus finding the height of the level

Steps 1 and 2 can be united if you convolve with the Laplacian of a gaussian kernel. A very good explanation for this edge detection algorithm is shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNP6ZwQ3r6A), explained by Shree K. Nayar